# Need a specific name/value pair from a JSON response

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, json, ssjs

I'm using SSJS, and I have an API call that returns the following JSON response:

```
{"StatusCode":200,"Response":["{\"id\":\"4623abc695724f0190e369a1c0f71f94\",\"title\":\"Link pna9\",\"slashtag\":\"pna9\",\"destination\":\"https://www.google.com/\",\"createdAt\":\"2020-10-28T22:19:51.000Z\",\"updatedAt\":\"2020-10-28T22:19:51.000Z\",\"status\":\"active\",\"tags\":[],\"clicks\":0,\"isPublic\":false,\"shortUrl\":\"kytracing.link/pna9\",\"domainId\":\"3ec0ccac84d84e2b88004ead1e375e03\",\"domainName\":\"kytracing.link\",\"domain\":{\"id\":\"3ec0ccac84d84e2b88004ead1e375e03\",\"ref\":\"/domains/3ec0ccac84d84e2b88004ead1e375e03\",\"fullName\":\"kytracing.link\",\"sharing\":{\"protocol\":{\"allowed\":[\"http\",\"https\"],\"default\":\"https\"}},\"active\":true},\"https\":true,\"favourite\":false,\"creator\":{\"id\":\"02567c89264b42a48452cbfb69248399\",\"fullName\":\"Deloitte Consulting\",\"avatarUrl\":\"https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/11898623d67933181a3df89567a70da4?size=80&d=retro&rating=g\"},\"integrated\":false}"]}
```

I'm having trouble trying to get the "shortUrl" name/value pair out of the response.  I don't know if the back slashes are causing the issue or what.  When I do a `ParseJSON(response)`, I have access to StatusCode and Response, but I'm not exactly sure how to further narrow this down and get something from within the Response value.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following and was able to get the shortUrl:

```
  var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
  var resultStringified = Stringify(result)
  var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(resultStringified);
  var objResp = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(obj.Response[0]);
  var shortUrl = objResp.shortUrl;
  Write(Stringify(shortUrl));
```

Comment: You can skip Stringifying it and Parsing it the first time. Can do `Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);` Also don't need to Stringify the short Url var when writing it.